# Dynamics CRM 2013: Issue with loading SavedView in an IFrame - Entity not found in Metadata

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

We recently migrated from CRM 4.0 to CRM 2013. There is a functionality where a saved view is loaded into an IFrame. When we use the same code, system throws a Query Builder error.

We already performed the below steps, but still getting the same error:
1. IIS Reset
2. Restarted the server
3. Created a new view and tried referencing with the new ID

Code:

```
var vDynamicForm = '<form name="vDynamicForm" method="post" 
action="/TMI/AdvancedFind/fetchData.aspx"?EntityCode=10013&QueryId="' 
+ Instance.QueryId + '"&ViewType=1039">' +

'<input type="hidden" name="FetchXml" value="' + Instance.FetchXml + 
'">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="LayoutXml" value="' + Instance.LayoutXml + 
'">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="EntityName" value=' + Instance.Entity + 
'>' +
//'<input type="hidden" name="EntityCode" value=10013>' +
'<input type="hidden" name="DefaultAdvFindViewId" value=' + 
Instance.QueryId + '>' +
'<input type="hidden" name="ViewType" value="1039">' +
'</form>';

m_iframeDoc.body.innerHTML = vDynamicForm;
m_iframeDoc.vDynamicForm.submit();
```

Error Log:
Error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Error Number: 0x80041102

Error Message: The entity with ObjectTypeCode = 0 was not found in the MetadataCache.

Error Details: The entity with ObjectTypeCode = 0 was not found in the MetadataCache.

Source File: Not available

Line Number: Not available

Request URL: "xyz.com/.../fetchData.aspx"